# How to solve mongodump timeout expiration?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I am trying to make a DB backup

```sh
mongodump -h <remote_ip>:27017 -d <db_name> -u <db_user> -p <db_pwd> --authenticationDatabase admin -o /root/mongodumps
```

But after a few minutes of the process, I get the error:

```sh
Failed: error writing data for collection `<db_name>.<col_name>` to disk: error reading collection: connection(<remote_ip>:27017[-4]) incomplete read of full message: read tcp <local_ip>:43970-><remote_ip>:27017: read: connection timed out
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely related to:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-2543

So after updating to mongodb 4.2.1 this should be fixed.

Comment: Does it work for you now? I have the same issue with mongodump version: 100.5.1

Comment: For me, updating the database worked and got rid of the timeout.